# Как убрать расширение файла из строки

Tags: c++, строки, c++11

Есть строка `std::string path1 = "/home/igor/tmp.123.zip"` 
Нужно программно превратить ее в строку `/home/igor/tmp.123` 
При этом алгоритм не должен трогать строки типа `std::string path2 = "/home/igor/tmp.123"` 
Расширение файла задано в `const std::string tail = ".zip";`

---

Как сделать это максимально быстро?

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Comment: @EOF Если будет строка home/igor/tmp.123.zip.zip - какой .zip вы удалите?

Comment: Хотел сказать "ну это же очевидно", но вспомнил, что из меня плохой объяснятор

Comment: @EOF Что будет для `"/chh.zip/jhfchj/ta.123"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убедиться, что конец строки совпадает с требуемым расширением, если да - убрать его.

Примерно так -

```
if (path1.size() < tail.size()) return;
if (path1.substr(path1.size()-tail.size(),tail.size())==tail)
{
    path1.erase(path1.size()-tail.size(),tail.size());
}
```

Если С++20 доступен - то можно проверить окончание с помощью `ends_with()`.

Еще вариант - использовать `path` из `<filesystem>`, но по сути то же самое...

```
string path1 = "/home/igor/tmp.123.zip";
string tail = ".zip";
filesystem::path path2 = path1;

if (path2.extension() == tail)
    path2.replace_extension();

cout << path2;
```

Comment: увы, но только c++11 и C++14

Comment: в C++17-, не создавая новую строку, окончание можно проверить через `find()`, если что...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Только тогда уж через `rfind()`. Можно и так.

Comment: @Harry а можно пример с rfind?

Comment: @Harry, для конца строки — всё равно, но на самом деле обе идеи кривые... `std::compare` или `std::equal` куда лучше выглядят: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874134/find-out-if-string-ends-with-another-string-in-c/42844629

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Заменить проверку на `if (path1.rfind(tail)==path1.size()-tail.size())`

Comment: @Fat-Zer И так тоже можно :)

Comment: @Harry, только вот так, чтобы не искать всю строку: `if (path1.find(tail, path1.size()-tail.size()) != string::npos)` ... и с `rfind` всё же не сработает — я рано согласился... ну и сравнение размеров не обязательно...

Comment: что-то я сегодня устал... с `rfind` то же самое будет...

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    std::string hello = "/home/igor/tmp.123.zip";
    const std::string tail = ".zip";
    size_t offset = hello.find_last_of(tail);
    if(offset != std::string::npos && offset == hello.length()-1)
    hello.erase(offset-tail.length()+1, tail.length());
    return 0;
}
```